# Deadlock while updating the same table - SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, deadlock, database-deadlocks

There is a stored procedure that updates pre_plan and pre_type for all associates. And it is deadlocking.

DDL of the visit and associate tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Associate](
    [pre_plan_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [pre_type_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [associate_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NOT NULL
)  

INSERT INTO Associate 
VALUES 
(NULL,  NULL,   -32768, 0),
(NULL,  NULL,   2,  1),
(NULL,  NULL,   3,  0),
(NULL,  NULL,   6,  1),
(NULL,  NULL,   3097,   1),
(NULL,  NULL,   3109,   0),
(NULL,  NULL,   3265,   1),
(NULL,  NULL,   3313,   0),
(NULL,  NULL,   3318,   1),
(NULL,  NULL,   3329,   0)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit](
    [type_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [plan_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [associate_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [time_in] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
) 
INSERT INTO Visit 
VALUES
(390,   31, 3109,   '2009-09-02'),
(304,   32, 3109,   '2010-02-05'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-09-24'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-09-27'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-09-27'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-09-28'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-10-01'),
(333,   28, 3109,   '2011-01-11'),
(338,   30, 3109,   '2011-01-18'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2011-01-27')
```

The stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_pre__] 

AS

UPDATE Associate SET pre_plan_id = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 plan_id 
         FROM Visit  
        WHERE associate_id = Associate.associate_id 
          AND time_in > 90
        GROUP BY plan_id 
        ORDER BY Count(*) DESC)
 WHERE deleted = 0

UPDATE Associate SET pre_type_id = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 [type_id] 
         FROM Visit 
        WHERE associate_id = Associate.associate_id 
          AND time_in > 90
        GROUP BY [type_id] 
        ORDER BY Count(*) DESC)
 WHERE deleted = 0
```

I was thinking to separate the transactions adding  `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` on both of the update statements. Will it help in avoiding the deadlock? Can anyone help me in suggesting most efficient way of avoiding the deadlock?

Comment: While it may make sense to wrap the two `update` statements in a single transaction, since they execute sequentially they can't deadlock with each other. What else is running that uses `Associate` and `Visit`?

Answer (score 0):

Meybe It is a idea to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` when using `SELECT CRUD` operation

**Its meaning,** using `READ UNCOMMITED` as a transaction isolation level on `SELECT` query.

> `With (NOLOCK)` refers to the current state of the table and ignores
>   other crud operations on the current operation. *important : You can miss uncommitted operation from different transactions in the selected table* (**dirty read**)

```
(SELECT TOP 1 [type_id] 
   FROM Visit With (NOLOCK)
  WHERE associate_id = Associate.associate_id 
    AND time_in > 90
GROUP BY [type_id] 
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC)
```

Comment: Allowing dirty reads usimg READ UNCOMMITTED or NOLOCK means that you are no longer guaranteed to get the correct results. It's a good practice to assume the correct results are required unless the client/end user states otherwise. Here's a couple articles that explain this in more detail. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Comment: @AlanBurstein I totally agree. I say readuncommitted operation and ignore other operations. I'm correcting it to be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

This procedure does not create a deadlock because two update statements will be executed sequential.  When you create and then run the following procedure (update_pre__test) which added the **BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN** block.  You can check the following DMV query which shows the open transactions in another query window. The DMV query shows only one open transaction which is related to this stored procedure.

However, we have to notice one think about deadlocks, we need two open transactions and there should be resource contention between them.

**Session-1:**

```
CREATE  [dbo].[update_pre__test]
AS BEGIN TRAN;
       UPDATE Associate
         SET pre_plan_id = (SELECT TOP 1 plan_id
                            FROM Visit
                            WHERE associate_id = Associate.associate_id
                                  AND time_in > 90
                            GROUP BY plan_id
                            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
       WHERE deleted = 0;
       UPDATE Associate
         SET pre_type_id = (SELECT TOP 1 [type_id]
                            FROM Visit
                            WHERE associate_id = Associate.associate_id
                                  AND time_in > 90
                            GROUP BY [type_id]
                            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
       WHERE deleted = 0;
       WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:02';
       COMMIT TRAN
```

**Session-2:**

```
    SELECT *
     FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tat
     INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests  er ON tat.transaction_id = er.transaction_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle)
```